# jquery how to call datepicker from another function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask your help guys. We have our own JS file which contains our defined functions. However, we want to have a reusable datepicker which we can use in different situation.

We have the code below.

```
 $.fn.ShowCalendar = function (pObjectName) {  
  this.find("#" + pObjectName).datepicker({
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   showButtonPanel: true,
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   minDate: new Date('2015/11/01'),
   maxDate: new Date('2016/05/31'),
   inline: true
  });
 };
```

In our page, we want to call it this way.

```
$("#datetest").ShowCalendar("datetest");
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="datetest" placeholder="To..." class="form-control"/>
```

But when we click the input box. the datepicker doesnt appear.
What we are missing with our code?

Comment: use $("#" + pObjectName).datepicker() instead of this.find("#" + pObjectName).datepicker(

Comment: Simply use `$("#datetest").ShowCalendar();` and `this.datepicker({`

Comment: your code above is showing the datepicker. However, the min and max date is not working.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm also using bootstrap on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,`$(this).datepicker({`
instead of  `this.find("#" + pObjectName).datepicker({`

Comment: I also tried your code Sir. the datepicker is showing. However, the min and max date is not working.

Comment: @shan.dye2 can you create a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
Just solve the problem. Since i'm using Bootstrap datepicker, i changed my code minDate and maxDate into startDate and endDate.

Thank you guys. :)